# I am unable to post data in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to post data to an express instance I have running when I post data using the `<form action="url" method="POST">` everything works corectly but when I try to do it through JavaScript using the code below I can only receive an empty object `{}`

```
loginButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const userName = document.getElementById("username").value;
    const passWord = document.getElementById("password").value;

    function post(url, data) {
        return fetch(url, { method: "POST", mode: 'no-cors', body: JSON.stringify(data) });
    }

    post("http://127.0.0.1:3200/login", {
        username: userName,
        password: passWord
    });
});
```

I have tried for hours to get it to work it will be amazing if you can help thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`<form action="url" method="POST">` is going to encode data using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format.

You are passing `fetch` a string of JSON, and since you haven't set a Content-Type header, it will infer a content-type of text/plain since you passed it a string.

Your server side code is, presumably, expecting application/x-www-form-urlencoded data and so fails to parse it.

Send application/x-www-form-urlencoded data:

```
function post(url, data) {
    const urlObject = new URLSearchParams();
    Object.entries(data).forEach( entry => urlObject.append(entry[0], entry[1]) );
    return fetch(url, { method: "POST", mode: 'no-cors', body: urlObject });
}
```

---

Note that `mode: 'no-cors'` will make it impossible to inspect the response to the request, which seems like it would be unhelpful since (presumably) the client needs to know if the attempt to login was successful or not.